# Applying for Schengen Visa, but through which embassy or consulate?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, europe

I'm planning for a Europe trip later this year in the following countries - Hungary, Austria, Czech Republic, Germany, Iceland and Netherlands.

The first country I would want to visit is Hungary, so I'll be booking my flights from Bangalore to Budapest with a 2 hours layover at Amsterdam. And my return will be from Amsterdam to Bangalore. 
 I'll be staying in Budapest for 3 nights, with Amsterdam being the longest duration of 5 nights.

I'm wondering through which country do I need to apply the Schengen visa from? Does it have to be issued by Hungarian embassy or the Netherlands embassy?

Because I have a layover in Amsterdam, does that count as my port of entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply for a Schengen visa via the country in which your longest stay will be, and if you plan to stay an equal time in multiple countries then you apply via the country which is your port of entry.

In your case, you should apply via the Netherlands.

> Because I have a layover in Amsterdam, does that count as my port of entry?

If you fly from Amsterdam to another Schengen country, then yes that counts as your port of entry into the Schengen area.  If you fly from Amsterdam via a non-Schengen country, it would not count as your port of entry into the Schengen area.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for that. Just a follow up question - Using the same visa from Netherlands, I can also travel to Iceland, right? I would want to spend a few days in Iceland, and then catch a return flight back from Amsterdam.

Comment: Yes (but you should mention it in your visa application as one of the countries you plan to visit.)